# The store schema does not contain the Element class SqlXmlCompressionOption

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, dacpac

I am doing or importing a bacpac file from azure SQL to SQL on-premises with SSMS and I am receiving this error.

> Details Could not load schema model from package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
>
> The store schema does not contain the Element class SqlXmlCompressionOption. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

SQL on premises Version (SQL server 2019)

[Versao SQL Server local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrDHH.png)

SQL Azure Version
[VersaoS Ql Server Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0a8U.png)

The command that generates or bacpac is here:

```
$exportRequest = New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ServerName $prdSqlServers.ServerName `
                -DatabaseName $DatabaseCopy -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" -StorageKey $StorageAccountKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
                -AuthenticationType "Sql" -AdministratorLogin $CredLocalSQL.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $CredLocalSQL.Password
```

I noticed that the model.xml file generated by bacpac has more than 1000 tags in this format

```xml
    <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
    <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
            <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
            <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
            <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
            <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
    <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
            <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
            <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
            <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
            <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) I also didn't know what *"Versao SQL Server local"* and *"VersaoS Ql Server Azure"* were meant to mean, so I haven't tried to correct the text there. Also, I note that you are *still* running the RTM version of SQL Server 2019; why haven't you updated your SQL Server instance in the last 3 years? There have been *multiple* significant bug and security fixes since September 2019.

Comment: Yes.  Update first, or try with the latest version of SqlPackage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Larnu About the update, I did what was asked

I ran the update and it still didn't work:

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU16-GDR) (KB5014353) - 15.0.4236.7 (X64) May 29 2022 15:55:47 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64 > (Build 19043: )

This error also occurs in SQL Server 2022 instance

 

 Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (CTP2.1) - 16.0.700.4 (X64) Jul 22 2022 16:01:16 Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19043: ) )

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft ,
I didn't have success either, I downloaded the latest version of DAC and ran the command below

run command : SqlPackage  /Action:Import /SourceFile:"D:\AzureError\database.bacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=NB114;Initial Catalog=database-v1; Integrated Security=true;"

Status : The store schema does not contain the Element class SqlXmlCompressionOption.

Comment: Looks like SqlPackage isn't in sync with the export service.  Can you create the bacpac with SqlPackage?  There's a new XML Compression feature in preview in Azure SQL Database and SQL Server 2022.

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft
the creation of the bacpack file is automated with this command that runs on a schedule in Automation Accounts
powershell: $exportRequest = New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ServerName $prdSqlServers.ServerName `
-DatabaseName $DatabaseCopy -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" -StorageKey $StorageAccountKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
-AuthenticationType "Sql" -AdministratorLogin $CredLocalSQL.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $CredLocalSQL.Password

Comment: @David Browne - Microsoft 
the import command  in on-premisse  server (SQL Server 2019 or SQL Server 2022)

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DAC\bin>SqlPackage /Action:Import /SourceFile:"source.bacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=newDB; Integrated Security=true;"

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem with Azure generated bacpacs. I succeeded in importing the bacpac using SSMS R19 preview 3.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-19?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Good morning , t
hank you very much for your willingness to help me , I just downloaded SSMS V19 preview 3 and it worked.
By the SSMS tool it works, but the same solution given, also has to be replicated for the SqlPackage.exe , because by the SqlPackage it still doesn't work.